# Rails won't find CSV fixtures

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, fixtures

I am trying to use CSV fixtures, but when I do `rake db:fixtures:load`, it complains about the lack of YAML files in `test/fixtures`. Everything works fine when the fixtures are in YAML and the files end in `.yml`.

Furthermore, when I look at the code in `activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb`, I see absolutely no reference to CSV processing. It appears that `fixtures.rb` only knows how to use YAML fixtures.

What is up here? Have CSV fixtures been deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV Fixtures are deprecated and support will be removed in Rails 3.2.0

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1716da07204193c8acf967e2d75a53a82e4c7c28#activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb