# CSV formated Fixtures or Factory Girl data (RUBY)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, fixtures

I have a number of CSV formatted files I would like to use as Fixtures or Factory Girl data.  I found this..

[Rails won't find CSV fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338903/rails-wont-find-csv-fixtures)

which states that CSV file support is deprecated.  What other solutions do I have to use CSV files as sample data with rspec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixtures are very hard to maintain and almost everybody is migrating to Factories. I encourage you to consider creating some factories instead of relying on fixtures, also considering your fixtures are in a format no longer supported.

It may take a little bit more at the beginning, but the maintenance will definitely be more effective.

You can create a script to parse the CSV and feed the database with your fixtures, but again, I do not encourage you to do that.

Comment: The sample data is from a CSV file that is acting as an input file, the input file will be transformed, with values changed and needs to be tested for the correct new values.  I'm not sure how factory girl can test something like that. Since the data is dependent on each other.  It's not just one record that needs to be tested, but a dependent number of values.  think a stock portfolio and market value percent, which is dependent on the stock value and the whole portfolio value, which is made of all the other portfolio values.